# Ant Design: Warning: [antd: Upload] `transformFile` is deprecated. Please use `beforeUpload` directly :ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using react ja to build an application. To build it i am using Ant Design library. From Ant Design i use `Upload`([link](https://ant.design/components/upload/)) component.

The component looks like this:

```js
<Upload
        name="file"
        listType="picture-card"
        className="avatar-uploader"
        showUploadList={true}
        action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{ width: '100%' }} /> : uploadButton}
</Upload>
```

Running the app in develop mode i get

```css
Warning: [antd: Upload] `transformFile` is deprecated. Please use `beforeUpload` directly.
warning @ warning.js:6
```

Question: Why this warning appears even i don't use `transformFile` in my component? 
 Also i don't want to use `beforeUpload`, why should i use it mandatory? Who faced with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your Antd version, to '4.12.3'

Answer (score 0):

That warning is removed from v4.10.0.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/releases/tag/4.10.0

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882888/group-inputs-in-react-js