# Group inputs in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ant design in my react application. I have the next Form:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Success:', values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="age"
        name="age"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        label="name"
        name="name"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        label="friends"
        name="friends"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Now when i submit the form i get an object with all these inputs name: `{name: 'test', age: 15, friends: 5}` I want another output of data, like this:

```js
user: [{
  meta: {
    age: 15,
    name: 'test'
  },
  other: {
    friends: 5
  }
}]
```

How to get the last output using my code?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4162-forked-44vq4?file=/index.js

Comment: did you try out some of the answers? Consider giving some feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to have a local variable which saves the state.

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from "antd";
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16
  }
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 8,
    span: 16
  }
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [array,setArray]=useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log({array})
  },[array.length])
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
    let other = {friends:values.friends}
    delete values.friends
    let temp_arr = [...array]
    temp_arr.push({meta:values, other})  
    setArray(temp_arr)
};

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item label="age" name="age">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="name" name="name">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="friends" name="friends">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values and change them to the desired value when setting the state.

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({}); // initialize state variable

const onFinish = (values) => {
  setUserData([{
    meta: {
      age: values.age, // set [0]meta.age to values.age
      name: values.name // and so on
    },
    other: {
      friends: values.friends
    }
  }]);
};
```

This will output

```js
[{
  meta: {
    age: "22"
    name: "Someone"
  },
  other: {
    friends: "5"
  }
}]
```

Updated [Sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4162-forked-np652?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by process the data on submit & then you can console.log or save in a database etc.

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const processData = ({ name, age, friends }) => {
    return {
      user: [
        {
          meta: {
            age,
            name
          },
          other: {
            friends
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }; // Step 1 - Create a helper function to process the form data

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Success:", processData(values)); // Pass the form data to that helper function
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item label="age" name="age">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="name" name="name">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="friends" name="friends">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/group-ant-design-data-29ps7

Let me know if you need further support.